# Retrieve all data from database to html table

Tags: asp.net, html, arraylist, foreach, html-table

Please can you help me how can I retrieve data from database to html table? I have written a script for it but I have problem with function foreach.

**Classs:**

```
public class games
{
    public string typeTicket { get; set; }
    public string typeMethod { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string typeName { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }

    public games(string typeTicket, string typeMethod, string message, string typeName, string value, string status)
    {
        this.typeTicket = typeTicket;
        this.typeMethod = typeMethod;
        this.message = message;
        this.typeName = typeName;
        this.value = value;
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

**Read data from DB:**

```
public ArrayList selectOrderGame()
{
    ArrayList hry = new ArrayList();
    commandS = new SqlCommand("SELECT typeTicket, typeMethod, message, typeName, value, status FROM dbo.tickets WHERE typeTicket LIKE 'Objednávka' AND typeMethod LIKE 'Hry'", conn);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = commandS.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string typeTicket = reader.GetString(0);
            string typeMethod = reader.GetString(1);
            string message = reader.GetString(2);
            string typeName = reader.GetString(3);
            string value = reader.GetString(4);
            string status = reader.GetString(5);

            games game = new games(typeTicket, typeMethod, message, typeName, value, status);
            hry.Add(game);
        }

        return hry;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

**Here is script for convert to html table:**

```
protected void FillPage()
{
    transaction tran = new transaction();
    ArrayList gameList = new ArrayList();
    if (IsPostBack)
        labelOutput.Text = "Při načítaní došlo k chybě";
    else
        gameList.Add(tran.selectOrderGame());

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (games game in gameList)
    {
        sb.Append(string.Format(@"<table>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan='6' width='150px'></th>
            <th width='50px'>Name: </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Type: </th>
            <th>{0}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Type: </th>
            <th>{1}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Type: </th>
            <th>{2}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Type: </th>
            <th>{3}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Type: </th>
            <th>{4}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Type: </th>
            <th>{5}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan='2'>{6}</td></tr>
        </table>", game.typeTicket, game.typeMethod, game.message, game.typeName, game.value, game.status));

        labelOutput.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Errors:**

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to type 'rad3k_eu.order.classes.games'.
>       Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>      Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to type 'rad3k_eu.order.classes.games'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace:**
>
> [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to type 'rad3k_eu.order.classes.games'.]
>       rad3k_eu.order.hry.FillPage() in
>    g:\Programování\Projects\C#\StreamingSite\StreamingSite\order\hry.aspx.cs:32
>       rad3k_eu.order.hry.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in g:\Programování\Projects\C#\StreamingSite\StreamingSite\order\hry.aspx.cs:18
>       System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
>       System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
>       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
>       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean inc ludeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

When I change this part code `gameList.Add(tran.selectOrderGame());` to `gameList = tran.selectOrderGame();` so error is fixed but convert to table still doesn't work, because `labelOutput` has still default name without my change.

Comment: An item in an ArrayList is an object. You read an element of the list as and object itself. So your `foreach` code should be `foreach(object o in gameList)`. You have to cast it to your target `game` object inside the `foreach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `selectOrderGame()` method returns an ArrayList, so I think you should change

```
gameList.Add(tran.selectOrderGame());
```

into

```
gameList = tran.selectOrderGame();
```

And you need to move this line out of the foreach loop:

```
labelOutput.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Otherwise the label text will always have the value of the last iteration

Comment: I change my comment down. Yep i have it and errors is fixed. Now i have problem that gameList count is 0. Maybe it was problem from DB.